Choosing projection for islands in South Pacific (specifically Tuvalu)
I'm working on a project for Tuvalu and most projections cut off pretty much exactly where Tuvalu is. They are ok for zoomed in maps but as the map cuts off directly to the east I can't show neighboring countries.

I have read about a few projections that center on the Pacific Ocean (e.g. EPSG:3832 or EPSG:32701) but they take a long time to load, and the layout map often doesn't load at all. I've got hardly any layers in the project and the layers I am using are very basic.

Any ideas as to another CRS or reasons why they take so long to load? It's doing my head in - sometimes it looks ok on the map but when I try and make a layout the map is missing big white areas (if it loads at all).

I'm using QGIS 3.36.3 if that's useful.

Are your basemaps WMS or a tile server?

My basemaps are WMS

As you are using WMS basemaps, likely what is happening is that requests for basemaps at the antimeridian really request very large "wrap around" map images that extend from the antimeridian the "long way around" back to the same point. You can verify this if you still see the same performance penalty trying to make a map at the same scale, but at 0° longitude rather than 180° longitude (the antimeridian).
If the WMS server doesn't natively support a map projection that has a false meridian at 180°, or other suitable projection specifically designed for Tuvalu (incidentally, I don't think there is one), then the map server really has no other option but to take a long time to respond with your basemap. The white areas are probably server time outs, i.e. where a request for a map image has taken so long that the request timed out.
I would try to download the basemaps locally, either side of the antimeridian, change the projection, and then stitch them together and use offline.
Alternatively, a WMTS server or TMS/XYZ server will respond more intelligenly than an equivalent WMS. You should probably be using these anyway if you can, WMS is becoming old-hat. (About the only reason to prefer WMS, from a provider perspective, is that handling map labels is easier.)
There may be a further issue simply related to the resolution of your exported map image; a higher resolution map is going to lead to more or more detailed map image requests, which will lead to greater likelihood of map server time outs.

Hello, all of that makes perfect sense however I am struggling with the reprojection and stitching process. I exported the map as an image and added it back to QGIS twice, changed the extent in Metadata to be -180 and 0 for one and 0 and 180 for the other but when I merge nothing happens. Any further tips? Thanks

Can you add details about how you're merging them? You should probably reproject them and then merge them. However if you don't need a specific basemap, looking for a TMS would likely be easier.

I added the same image twice with the same CRS (EPSG:4326) and in Metadata under Layer Properties I changed the West extent to -180 and East to 180 for one, and west to 180 and east to 540 for the other (I also tried -180 to 0 and 0 to 180 respectively). After that I tried to Merge the two but it just overlays them on top of each other as though the extents were never changed and the output is exactly the same albeit slightly darker

Are you able to share the WMS URL? I'm trying to reproduce the issue, but the services I'm using seem to work fine without any workarounds at all.

Yep, https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

any luck? I still can't seem to get it sorted.

What you're using there is not WMS, but TMS/XYZ. As such, the tiles are only natively available in EPSG:3857. When working in alternative projections, which you need to do to span across the antimeridian, your map client (QGIS) is responsible for working out which tiles to request, putting them together, and performing map re-projection. That is not an altogether light process, and QGIS probably isn't caching more than the tiles as received from the server. Best bet would be to try other map servers, it seems like the one you've linked above is just very slow.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.modestmaps.bluemarble/{z}-r{y}-c{x}.jpg. Try it with EPSG:8859, which works fine for me.
